# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist Spring Data source

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am converting working hibernate project to Spring hibernate Project.In the existing project session factory creation has been done by loading hibernate cfg file.Since im going for spring i modified the session creation via Localsessionfactory by configuring in java.I am getting one strange exception as below

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But the same working fine in the hiberate cfg lookup.

I am using two transcation manager .Below is my code
Repository clas

```
@Repository
public class TestImpl implements
        TestRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fSessionFactory")
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dSessionFactory")
    SessionFactory sessionFactory2;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional("dTransaction")
    public  Recordse getOrders(String code, int id   ) throws PersistenceException {
            Session session = null;
        try {
            session =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            List<Order> orderList  =  session
                    .createQuery("FROM Orders WHERE CODE = :code  AND NUM_CC = :id " )
                    .setParameter("code", code)
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .list();            
                    }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e);
        }


        return empSickTime ;
    }

    @Transactional("fTransaction")
    @Override
    public SelectedRecords getRecords(String code, String grpId) throws PersistenceException {
        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = sessionFactory2.getCurrentSession();

            List<Records> recList  =  session
                    .createQuery("FROM Records WHERE CODE = :code  AND GRP_CC = :id " )
                    .setParameter("code", code)
                    .setParameter("id", id)
                    .list();            
                    }


        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new PersistenceException(e);
        }

        return qualifiedFleet;
    }


}
```

PersistencConfig1

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.test2.*" })
public class PersistenceConfiguration1 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="    ")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(testDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                " com.test.test2"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties1());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource testDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="dTransaction")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties1() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

PersistenceConfig2

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.test3.*" })
public class PersistenceConfigurationDOTC {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="dSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(test1DataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                "com.test.test3.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource test1DataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc1.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc1.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc1.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc1.pass"));

        return dataSource;
    }

     @Bean(name = "fTransaction")
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryFCDS().getObject());

        return txManager;
    }



    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: You are probably connecting to wrong Oracle instance and/or Oracle schema, could you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean(name="    ")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
```

It looks like your bean name is incorrect?

Another thing is in your `fTransaction` you are using session factory from your `dSessionFactory` as you declare `sessionFactory2`

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dSessionFactory")
SessionFactory sessionFactory2;
```

and then use in `fTransaction`

```
@Transactional("fTransaction")
@Override
public SelectedRecords getRecords(String code, String grpId) throws PersistenceException {
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory2.getCurrentSession();
```

I guess you are referring to the wrong DB connection.

Next time I would suggest giving your attributes more meaningful names, like `paymentSessionFactory`, `geoSessionFactory` & etc so that you won't mix `var1` vs `session2`